# Lazy loading Vuex module with NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

Can anyone help me Lazy loading Vuex module?

Where am I doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/py197qvxx?fontsize=14

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store.registerModule dont return promise, so there no then on it. You just call it and then do your dispatch.

Also you preserveState option. Read this issue https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4370

So your code would be following:

```
  async asyncData({ store, params }) {
    console.log(Users);
    store.registerModule("Users", Users, { preserveState: false });
    await store.dispatch("Users/GET_USER_INFO", params.index);
  },
```

But code in asyncData executed either on client or server, not on both. So on first load on user page it will be only executed on server, and on client tehre wont be registered module. So you cant do that in asyncData if u want it to work both on client side navigation on server side. Something like created hook will work better

Comment: on client Side browsing or client-side button click working fine but on hard refresh or server-side request throwing an error

Comment: Yes, Correct one option is in the created hook. But what to do API calls/ DISPATCH action in asyncData that also need to be a move to created hook. Created hook called twice from server/client side correct!!
Can we achieve this client/server-side scenario module registration and first API calls in fetch method??

Comment: @HardikShah you cant, because fetch cant be called both on client and server. So you still will need to register modules on client. So you can check for example on client in beforeCreate hook whether or not module was loaded and if not load it